# Encrypt using Triple DES in C#, decrypt in perl

Tags: c#, perl, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a string of text in C# using triple des. The text eventually needs to be decrypted using perl. The text coming out the other end still looks like gobblygyk. Am I missing a flag on the cipher?

C# encrypt:

```
    public static string EncryptString(string str)
    {
        using (var provider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            provider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            provider.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("THISIS24BYTESWORTHOFTEXT");
            provider.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("01234567");
            provider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            var hashBytes = EncryptStringToBytes(str, provider);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);  
        }
    }

    private static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string txt, TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desAlg)
    {

        var encryptor = desAlg.CreateEncryptor(desAlg.Key, desAlg.IV);

        using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(txt);
                }
            }
            return msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

perl decrypt:

```
sub DecryptString { 
my ($dbh, $args) = @_;

my $inargs = $args->{INPUT};
my $key="THISIS24BYTESWORTHOFTEXT";
my $iv = "01234567";

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
        -cipher => 'DES_EDE3',
        -key => $key,
        -literal_key => 1,
        -iv => $iv,
        -add_header => 0,
        -keysize => 24,
);

return $cipher->decrypt($inargs);
}
```

Comment: This may or may not help, but I'm guessing that the perl is probably using utf8 encoding instead of the ascii encoding you are using on the C# side. Change the C# to use utf8 encoding and give it another try.

Comment: **Do not use Tripple DES for new work**, it is no longer considered secure , use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard). AES has essentially the same interface as 3DES so is no harder to use.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to decode before decrypting. As per the comment below, I changed the call to

$inargs = decode_base64($inargs);

right before call to decrypt.

Comment: That whole function is already provided by `use MIME::Base64 qw( decode_base64 );`

Comment: No reason to use IO::Scalar after Perl 5.6